# Why is adb not found?

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, adb

I just installed the ADT bundle with eclipse on a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.10.  Now when I try to run adb I get this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1q9S.png[image]

what's going on??

Comment: hi 
add the path of adb in bashrc file...

or use export path=pathofthefile and then try

Comment: Exact same issue was answered from Superuser

[http://superuser.com/questions/344533/no-such-file-or-directory-error-in-bash-but-the-file-exists][1]


  [1]: http://superuser.com/questions/344533/no-such-file-or-directory-error-in-bash-but-the-file-exists

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Quynh Nguyen.  The solution is:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```